# Always Encrypted - Out of Memory Exception when attempting to encrypt a column in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, alter-table, ddl, always-encrypted

Using Always Encrypted we are attempting to encrypt one column of type varchar(50) in a table that contains 5.5 million rows with the deterministic encryption. After a while the wizard returns failure due to the following error:

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown..
```

Any ideas on how to prevent this error?

Comment: What are you using to do the encryption? (SSIS, C# app, what?) Where are you running it? (On the SQL Server itself, or on a separate app server?)

Comment: @BrentOzar I am using SSMS and it's running on the SQL Server itself.

Comment: yeah, 32-bit SSMS isn't exactly known for its high-performance memory management. Time to step up to something bigger.

Comment: @BrentOzar I am using 64-bit SSMS.

Comment: There is no such thing, on 32-bit or 64-bit machines, SSMS is based on a 32-bit visual studio shell and is subject to all the limitations that imposes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Ahh, I see - they fooled me by putting "x64"'s in the file names! Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Yeah that just means it's the installer for that platform - there are still a couple of differences there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your table have a primary key or a clustered index? There is a known issue in the wizard/PowerShell that may cause it to run out of memory, if the table does not have a primary or a clustered index, so one workaround could be to create a primary key/clustered index, if you don't have it already.

You can also try to use 64-bit PowerShell. Using 32-bit PowerShell instead of SSMS will likely not help, as SSMS and PowerShell use the same library (DacFx) to support most Always Encrypted scenarios.

Comment: Wait, people still use 32-bit Powershell? On purpose?

Comment: @user118250 - your answer worked as well - I added a primary key (not the field I was trying to encrypt) to the table, ran the wizard, and the encryption completed successfully.

Answer (score 4):

For large tables I would definitely work with T-SQL or Powershell rather than the wizard - clunky UIs that run all kinds of background things and take over-protective locks do not have a great track record. For example, this wizard actually offers an option to generate Powershell:

> [image]

I would do that. Here is what it produces:

```posh
# Generated by SQL Server Management Studio at 9:10 PM on 2/22/17

Import-Module SqlServer
# Load reflected assemblies

[reflection.assembly]::LoadwithPartialName('System.Data.SqlClient') | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::LoadwithPartialName('Microsoft.SQLServer.SMO') | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::LoadwithPartialName('Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectionInfo') | Out-Null

# Set up connection and database SMO objects

$sqlConnectionString = 'Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Packet Size=4096;Application Name="Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"'
$sqlConnection = New-Object 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' $sqlConnectionString
$serverConnection = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection' $sqlConnection
$smoServer = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server' $serverConnection
$smoDatabase = $smoServer.Databases['DatabaseName']

# If your encryption changes involve keys in Azure Key Vault, uncomment one of the lines below in order to authenticate:
#   * Prompt for a username and password:
#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -Interactive

#   * Enter a Client ID, Secret, and Tenant ID:
#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -ClientID '<Client ID>' -Secret '<Secret>' -Tenant '<Tenant ID>'

# Change encryption schema

$encryptionChanges = @()

# Add changes for table [dbo].[TableName]
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName dbo.TableName.ColumnName -EncryptionType Deterministic -EncryptionKey ColumnKey

Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges -InputObject $smoDatabase
```

Now, this still might take a long time; I haven't done thorough benchmarks on encrypting existing data. But you won't run out of memory (this error was because of SSMS limitations, not SQL Server's).

I looked quickly and, while it is easy to generate T-SQL scripts for creating master and column keys, I don't know of a way to run ALTER TABLE. This passes syntax checks:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
ALTER COLUMN ColumnName varchar(11)   
        COLLATE  Latin1_General_BIN2 ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = ColumnKey,  
        ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC ,  
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256');
```

However it fails at runtime with:

> Msg 206, Level 16, State 2
>   
> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(11) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'ColumnKey', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'DatabaseName') collation_name = 'Latin1_General_BIN2'

Comment: I tried your PowerShell suggestion and it worked, thank you! It took around 2 hours and seemed to be stuck on "100% Completed" for most of the time, but in the end the job was done. Seeing more and more that SSMS falls short because of its limitations.

Comment: @RoastBeast Generally, any time I open up a dialog or wizard in SSMS, I get suspicious. Most have a little script drop down to generate the script it would have produced if you let the UI do it - I grab those and inspect them before running them myself in a query window.